# How can I solve the thread error EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I want to fix an error of thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x30) i m getting this error when i click on button ,button code is given below

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    DBHandler *db = [[DBHandler alloc]init];

    word_id = [[NSString alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"String %@",word_id);

    [db addFavoriteWord:word_id];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)nextView:(id)sender {
}

@end
```

Comment: i don t know why i am giving error i have tried many time :(

Comment: Do you have the rest of the error log, or can you elaborate on exactly what line the error is thrown on. What are the steps to recreate the error, and which part of this code is the 'button code'. If you are referring to the IBAction, then i can not see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Success Query: insert into favorite_word( favorite_word_id) values('0')

(lldb)

Comment: can i send you my project so you can check it if there are any mistakes?

Comment: you could, but I'm browsing off of my phone so I couldn't see it. What is the output of the NSLog line? I am guessing it is empty. try changing word_id = [[NSString alloc] init];  to word_id = @"test"; and see if it works after that. The error may be because your database is expecting characters in your string.

Comment: What code is there in button click event ? there is nothing ?

Comment: i did by changing word_id to @"test"; my log message is

Comment: 2012-10-19 12:19:04.552 Islamic dictionary[1443:c07] CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL WITH DB
2012-10-19 12:19:04.670 Islamic dictionary[1443:c07] QUERY: select * from word GROUP BY alphabet
2012-10-19 12:19:05.909 Islamic dictionary[1443:c07] QUERY: SELECT * FROM word WHERE alphabet like 'A'
2012-10-19 12:19:07.145 Islamic dictionary[1443:c07] String test


Success Query: insert into favorite_word( favorite_word_id) values('0')

(lldb)

Comment: 2012-10-19 12:23:23.203 Islamic dictionary[1476:c07] -[__NSCFString nextView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x758b390
2012-10-19 12:23:23.339 Islamic dictionary[1476:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString nextView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x758b390'

Comment: *** First throw call stack:
(0x2098012 0x11a5e7e 0x21234bd 0x2087bbc 0x208794e 0x11b9705 0xf0920 0xf08b8 0x1b1671 0x1b1bcf 0x1b0d38 0x12033f 0x120552 0xfe3aa 0xefcf8 0x1ff3df9 0x1ff3ad0 0x200dbf5 0x200d962 0x203ebb6 0x203df44 0x203de1b 0x1ff27e3 0x1ff2668 0xed65c 0x1f9d 0x1ec5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: `-[__NSCFString nextView:]:` how did you call nextView?

Comment: check where you are calling `nextView:` it is definitely sent to the wrong object (of type `NSString`). Are you maybe doing something like `myButton = myString` instead of `myButton.text = myString` ?

Comment: Bingo, that'll be it, well done. A pointer which the compiler thinks at an instance of this viewController subclass above is being set to point instead at your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change code:

```
word_id = [[NSString alloc]init];
```

on

```
word_id = [NSString stringWithString:@""];
```